# beginner: django json cache-control IE progressbar

Tags: django, internet-explorer

Disclaimer: I am a beginner with django but have drupal coding experience

After researching the IE cache-control issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294155/ajax-request-that-returns-json-array-ie6-7-is-caching-it-and-data-is-not-fresh), my .getJSON (which refreshes every 200 ms to update a .jqueryui progressbar) is working great in Firefox, but not IE, despite forcing IE NOT to cache, like this:

```
#views.py
...
response = HttpResponse(vars,mimetype='application/json; charset=utf8')
response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
return response
```

In IE 9's Fiddler, I receive the following, showing that IE is sending the request:

```
URL Method  Result  Type    Received    Taken   Initiator   Wait‎‎  Start‎‎     Request‎‎   Response‎‎  Cache read‎‎    Gap‎‎

/import-cmd-get-progress/?_=1332361628456   GET 200 application/json    166 B   < 1 ms  JS Library XMLHttpRequest   11248   0   0   0   0   203

/import-cmd-get-progress/?_=1332361628566   GET 200 application/json    166 B   16 ms   JS Library XMLHttpRequest   11357   0   16  0   0   78
/import-cmd-get-progress/?_=1332361628657   GET 200 application/json    166 B   < 1 ms  JS Library XMLHttpRequest   11451   0   0   0   0   0
```

but somehow, IE won't show the progressbar, so I suspect that I'm sending the wrong headers. Thoughts? Again, this works great in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The problem was poor programming on my part. I was returning

```
[object {something:something}]
```

instead of

```
{something:something}
```

Firefox understood my data[0] but not Internet Explorer.